# Using the python library "pre-commit", how can I add a git pre-commit hook that runs a single python file?

Tags: git, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit.com

I am using [this](https://pre-commit.com/) library to try and add a pre-commit hook to my project. It's a lot to take in and I don't think the pre-commit check I want needs the large scope most of their examples use. All I want to do, is run a single python file. Depending on if that file exited/finished without issue (IE no exceptions raised) is what I want to allow or disallow commits on. I have made a `.pre-commit-config.yaml` but I don't know how to make it run only a single file.

I basically want typing `git commit -m "whatever"` to automatically run `python myfile.py` <- and based on the exit code of this, allow or prevent a commit. any idea on what my yaml should look like?

Here is what I have so far:

```
repos:
-   repo: local
    hooks:
    - id: translation-file-check
      name: Check Translation Files Are Aligned
      description: This hook ensures that all translation files share the same set of keys and generates a CSV if there are no issues
      language: python
      entry: "./dir/subdir/myfile.py"
```

But I get the following error: `.An unexpected error has occurred: OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application`
 I think because it is expecting this .py file to be a .exe or something even though I set `language` to python...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

pretty close!  there's two ways to make this work:

1. add a "shebang" (`#!/usr/bin/env python`) to your file

   - even though shebangs are a posix thing, `pre-commit` contains code which normalizes platforms and makes them work on windows as well!
2. use `entry: python ./dir/subdir/myfile.py`

   ```
   repos:
   -   repo: local
       hooks:
       - id: translation-file-check
         name: Check Translation Files Are Aligned
         description: This hook ensures that all translation files share the same set of keys and generates a CSV if there are no issues
         language: python
         entry: python ./dir/subdir/myfile.py
   ```

(disclaimer: I am the author of `pre-commit`)

Comment: Both of those answers worked! thanks! I am now getting module not found errors because I have never tried to run this .py file from a different directory but since that is more of a python issue I am going to accept your answer.